# Cannot set instance properties on Vue 2 & Axios API call

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, vuejs2, axios

I'm making an API call as follows in Vue 2.0 using the Axios library.

```
axios.get(API_URL + '/products?country=' + code, {headers: { Authorization: 'Basic c3VyZWJ1ZGR5LWFwaS11c2VyOkFwaTQzMjJTdXJlYg==' }})
           .then((response) => {
              console.log(response);
              //this.products = response.data;
            })
           .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
```

With "this.products = response.data;" commented out I get a perfect response like so:

[image]

When I want to attach the server response to this.products so I can output it in the view I get the following:

[image]

I am able to access the keys like code and country but I cannot access the details array.

Stuck right now and can't think of what else to do right now.

My data object looks as follows:

```
data: 
{
country: "",
countries: "",

product: "",
products: "",

country_selected: "",
product_selected: "",

singleProduct: "",
},
```

Comment: you should initialise `products ` with empty hash: `{}`, however this will not solve your issue, just hygiene.

Comment: What do you get , when you print `this.products.details`?

Comment: @Saurabh If I console log console.log(this.products); after the API call it returns an empty array. this.products.details is undefined. I'm not sure why it's not assigning the property.

Comment: The reactive getters are added by Vue, that's how it observes changes and reacts to them. What do you see when you click `details(...)` in that output?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running your `axios` request? I've mocked up a quick demo based on your code above and it seems to work for me? Check it out --> https://jsfiddle.net/stursby/nz8h6anL/

A few notes:

- I'm settings products to an empty Array
- Calling `axios` in the `mounted` lifecycle hook

Depending on where your code is, your context of `this` might be bound to `axios` and not the Vue instance.

Here's my Vue specific code:

```
// Generated via --> http://beta.json-generator.com/NyhG4qTDf
const API = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/tbeuh'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    products: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get(API).then((res) => {
      this.products = res.data
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: I asked the API developers to change the structure of the API. The problem I was having is that in the view I could not access the details array. I have a suspicion though that it was outputting it as a string in the view and therefore didn't see details as an array?!